# Footnotes in longtable captions

Tags: footnotes, longtable

Is there a way to put a footnote in longtable caption?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

  \begin{longtable}{|c|}
    \caption{Table 
    %    \footnote{Footnote}    % Uncommenting results in error.
    } \\   
    \hline      
    Something \\
    \hline      
  \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `longtable` documentation:

> Note however that `\footnote` will not work in the ‘head’ or ‘foot’
>   sections of the table. In order to put a footnote in those sections
>   (e.g., inside a caption), use `\footnotemark` at that point, and
>   `\footnotetext` anywhere in the table body that will fall on the same
>   page.

Hence the MWE will be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|}
    \caption[Table is very long]{Table is very long\protect\footnotemark}\\ %<------footnote mark here
    \hline
    Something \footnotetext{This is a caption} \\ %<------footnote text here
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Added short caption as per Gonzalo's suggestion. With short caption added, `\protect` won't be necessary.

[image]

Comment: It could be sensible to use the optional argument of  `\caption`, as in `\caption[Table is very long]{Table is very long\protect\footnotemark}` to prevent the mark from having a wrong numbering in the text and from appearing also in a possible list of figures

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, Thanks, I have made the changes.

Comment: With the changes made, `\protect` is unnecessary.

Comment: I am trying this as well. My documentclass is report. It returns errors if I don't use \protect. It does not produce any notes either with \protect\footnotetext or with \protect\footnotemark.

Comment: @Costi: What errors you get? For me it works. May be you should update your packages.

Comment: How do I update them?

Comment: @Costi: Refer [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/55473#55473)

Answer (score 3):

You can keep the normal `\footnote` command by using the `footnotehyper` package:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{footnotehyper}
\makesavenoteenv{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|}
  \caption[tab]{Table\footnote{Footnote}} \\   
  \hline
  Something \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```